# How do I limit options using argparse

Tags: python, python-2.7

What I need is when my script executes with --history switch, the only options allowed from general options is limited to -g or -c but not -s or anything else.

so **script.py --history -g grp1** is allowed and **script.py --history -c cluster1** is allowed, however **script.py --history -s sys1** is not allowed.
Also **script.py --history --by-date** is allowed so is **script.py --history --by-date -g grp1** and **script.py --history --by-date -c cluster1** How can this be limited with ArgumentParser.

```
arg_parser = ArgumentParser(description='Description')
    main_options = arg_parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
    main_options.add_argument('--history', action='store_true',
                              help='Display event history.')

history_flags = arg_parser.add_argument_group(
        'History Options',
        description='bla'
        history_flags.add_argument('--by-date', action='store_true',
                            help='Sort history by date, not group.')

flags = arg_parser.add_argument_group('General Options')
flags.add_argument('-g', dest='group',
                   help='help')
flags.add_argument('-c', dest='cluster',
                   help='help')
flags.add_argument('-s', dest='system',
                   help='help')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem as below:

```
args = arg_parser.parse_args()

if args.group and args.cluster and args.system:

    args.error('Set -g -c -s is not allowed!')
```

Comment: That would work fine if General Options only had those three entries, but there are more options which makes the if condition very long. And if new general options are being introduced code needs to be updated in two places. I was hoping for a solution within ArgumentParser if there is any.